# Relative clause construction

Tags: relative-clauses

In an exercise book for college students, the teacher asked the students to combine the following sentence using a relative pronoun:

> Shakespeare was a famous writer. He wrote great plays.

The teacher's answer was as follows:

> Shakespeare was a famous writer who wrote great plays.

lsn't it better to combine the sentence as follows?

> Shakespeare, who wrote great plays, was a famous writer.

Answer (score 1):

I think both sentences are technically acceptable, but people will no doubt have different opinions about which sentence is correct.

I think that if the reader doesn't know who or what Shakespeare is then your teacher's first choice is best because the reader will probably want to know that Shakespeare was a writer (first).

The clause then goes on to add more information i.e. it functions as an adjective clause which is what a relative clause is.

Comment: I agree with the teacher's construction.  I think consigning Shakespeare's playwriting to an appositive seems to relegate his playwriting genius to a throw-in.  The most important point is carried in the main phrase, and all that does is tell the reader that Shakespeare was a famous writer.  To me the fact that he wrote great plays is in the main clause, and the fact that he was a famous writer should take second place in the relative subordinate clause,  I also prefer the form of a relative clause to a mere appositive in this example